# For which values of $p \in \mathbb{R} $ is the integral $I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^p}{x^2+a^2}dx$ convergent?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

> For which values of $p \in  \mathbb{R}$ is the integral $I =
> \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^p}{x^2+a^2}dx$ convergent?  Evaluate the
> integral by residue calculations for those values for which it is
> convergent.

I am making this exercise in preparation for my Complex Analysis exam.
I begin by noticing that $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^p}{x^2+a^2} < \infty$. So we have that $p<2$.

Now we want to use a toy contour to solve the integral. We have the poles $i\sqrt{a}$, $-i\sqrt{a}$ and $0$ if $p<0$. So we make the toy contour that is clockwise the semi circle on the upper half complex plane with radius R, $\gamma_R$. Then the real axis from $-R$ to $R$ but around zero we add a little bow so that when zero would be a pole this would not be a problem,$\gamma_{\epsilon}$.

The integral becomes: $ I = \int_{\gamma_R} \frac{x^p}{x^2+a^2}dx + \int_{\gamma_{\epsilon}} \frac{x^p}{x^2+a^2}dx + \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{x^p}{x^2+a^2}dx$.

Now we want to say $z(t) = e^{it}$. But now I get a little bit lost. Do I then need to solve this three integrals?

I do not get how I need to solve this kind of proves further. Does anyone has a general strategy and can show for values of p that $I$ converges, by applying it on this example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $ a\ne 0$, it converges if $ 2-p>1$ By the limit comparison test.

Answer (score -1):

Near zero, you need $p>-1$ to avoid a non-integrable singularity, while hear infinity, you must have $p<1$ so that the decay is fast enough. Thus your range is $-1<p<1.$